# Javascript - $(this).on

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why it can retrieve the "modelValue" when inputText changed ?
Who can describe the flow of this script ?
Thanks

```js
//js預載入
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready!");
  var iepValues = $('body').find('[model-value]');
  $.each(iepValues, function() {
    var modelValue = $(this).attr('model-value');
    console.log("display");
    //Why it can retrive the "modelValue" when inputText chagned ?
    $(this).on('change', function() {
      console.log("modelValue:" + modelValue);
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

  TEST1:
  <input type="text" id="TxtTest1" model-value="A">TEST2:
  <input type="text" id="TxtTest2" model-value="B">

</body>
```

Comment: i dont see any problem. it gets the value of the input as it should be

Comment: Are you looking the script explained as to how it works?

Comment: To  guradio, thank u for your answer. I want to know how it works. 
To Adil, thank u for your helping
To NiallMitch, Yes

Comment: You shouldn't use nonstandard attribute names like `model-value`. If you need your own attributes, use `data-XXX`, like `data-model-value="A"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why it can retrieve the "modelValue" when inputText changed ?

Because the function hooked up with `$(this).on('change', function() { ... });` is called when the value of the input changes, and that function *closes over* (has access to) the `modelValue` variable in context where it was created.

> Who can describe the flow of this script ?

1. It calls jQuery's `ready` function, passing in a function to call when the DOM is ready. All of the rest of the code is in that callback.
2. When the DOM is ready, jQuery calls the callback.
3. The code logs `"ready!"` and the finds all elements inside `body` that have a `model-value` attribute. [Side Note: `$('body').find('[model-value]')` can more concisely and efficiently be written `$('body [model-value]')`.]
4. The code loops through all of those elements using `$.each`, calling a callback function for each of them.
5. Inside *that* callback, the code grabs the value of the `model-value` attribute and stores it in a variable. There will be a different variable for each of the elements, each variable contained by the context of the call to the callback from `$.each`.
6. Code in each of those callbacks hooks up a handler for the `change` event of that element.
7. The handler responds to the change event by logging the value of the `modelValue` variable.

Recommended reading:

- [The jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com)
- [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)
- [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

If the element's `model-value` attribute is going to change, that code will log the value it had when the DOM was ready, not the value it has when the `value` of the input changes. That would seem to be the point of the code.

If the `model-value` attribute *doesn't* change, then the code is unnecessarily complicated, and could just be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready!");
  $('body [model-value]').on('change', function() {
    console.log("modelValue:" + $(this).attr('model-value'));
  });
});
```

Or even:

```
console.log("ready!");
$('body [model-value]').on('change', function() {
  console.log("modelValue:" + $(this).attr('model-value'));
});
```

If you move the `script` tag to the bottom of the HTML, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

But again, that's if the `model-value` attribute doesn't change, or if you want to see the changed value instead of the original value. The original code will show you the original, not changed, value of the attribute.